# Python MongoDB Find One

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to find by id a document in the database, but I get `None`. What am I doing wrong?

python:

```
card = mongo.db['grl'].find_one({'id': 448510476})
```

or:

```
card = mongo.db['grl'].find_one({'id': '448510476'})
```

document:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f25b1d787fc4c34a7d9aabe"},
"id":{"$numberInt":"448510476"},"first_name":"Arc","last_name":"Fl"}
```

[image]

Comment: do you able to get the output if you use any other field?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are initializing your database but try this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
db = client.database #Selecting database named "database"

#find one in collection named "collection"    
card = db.collection.find_one({"id": "448510476"})

print(card)
```